# Best way to do reporting in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3 project. This time i need to go for reporting for my project. My reporting requirements are something like it should be **Drill Down** support, **Graphs**(Pie Chart, Bar chart etc). Is there any better tool available based on my requirement at free of cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports
Is the better tool to *cool* reports and *Graphs* and _Drill_Down_. It have a free version. Good luck !
btw.. its eazy to build reports.

take a look to this link http://crystal.brothersoft.com/crystal-report-c.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Is there any other tool available for MVC3 except Crystal Reports?

Comment: maybe, but i have 5 years developing.. and 3 companies, never heard about another *Reporter* better or equal.